# QML: What is the difference between Row and TemplateRow?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml

TemplateRow is just an example out of several.

There is also TemplateSection and I assume TemplateColumn as well as many others.

When should I be using Row{} vs TemplateRow{}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template, TemplateFlow, TemplateRow, TemplateSection and TemplateSectionNavigation are all internal components used by the `ubuntu-ui-toolkit-examples` package (See the full list [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/ubuntu-ui-toolkit-examples/filelist)).

To run the gallery, just type in a terminal:

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/examples/ubuntu-ui-toolkit-gallery/gallery
```

They are not standard components of the Ubuntu SDK but show how you can use and reuse QML elements across your application(s).

Comment: In short; I would never **need** to use them?

Comment: Exactly, all those qml elements are just part of the gallery. Only pure Row and Column are standard components